# I want a .png Image as background of a form in vb6.0

Tags: vb6, splash-screen

I'm making a splash screen in vb6.0, I've managed to make the form transparent, But now I want to display a png image as the background picture of a form, So I'll get proper look of a splash screen.

Comment: What is the problem? You can't use a PNG file as a background, or a PNG won't become transparent as opposed to e.g. JPEG?

Comment: I'm unable to use .png as a background @GSerg

Comment: png format isn't directly supported. You have a few options: 1. Convert the png to a jpg. 2. Do a google search for vb6 png load picture. 3. Update to a modern programming language such as vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Splash screens" went out of style with Windows 3.1, and pretty much disappeared in serious software shortly afterward.  But you can do this kind of thing with little trouble.

It sounds like you want this splash screen to have "holes in it" where the PNG is transparent, for example perhaps a borderless Form you want to display as an irregular image.  You'd need to render the PNG image on top of your backdrop chroma-key color.

However since OLE/ActiveX has no transparent PNG rendering support VB doesn't offer a direct way to do this.  Your options include things like the GDI+ Flat API or a GDI+ wrapper library such as WIA 2.0.  WIA 2.0 has been part of Windows for a very long time now.  It ships in Vista and later, and was once available as a redist library for Windows XP SP1 and later.

Here's a brief example using WIA 2.0 which is fairly short to post.  Note that it assumes the Project has a reference to `Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library 2.0` set:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowLongW" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowLongW" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIndex As Long, _
    ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal crKey As Long, _
    ByVal bAlpha As Byte, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
Private Const WS_EX_LAYERED = &H80000
Private Const LWA_COLORKEY = &H1&

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim W As Long
    Dim H As Long
    Dim ScanWidth As Long
    Dim Backdrop() As Byte
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim X As Long
    Dim BackImgF As WIA.ImageFile

    'Set the Form "transparent by color."
    SetWindowLong hWnd, _
                  GWL_EXSTYLE, _
                  GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) Or WS_EX_LAYERED
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 1), 0, LWA_COLORKEY

    'Render PNG image into the Form with transparency.
    W = ScaleX(ScaleWidth, ScaleMode, vbPixels)
    H = ScaleY(ScaleHeight, ScaleMode, vbPixels)
    ScanWidth = ((3 * W + 3) \ 4) * 4
    ReDim Backdrop(ScanWidth * H - 1)
    For Y = 0 To H - 1
        For X = 0 To W - 1
            Backdrop(ScanWidth * Y + 3 * X) = 1 'RGB(0, 0, 1)
        Next
    Next
    With New WIA.Vector
        .BinaryData = Backdrop
        Set BackImgF = .ImageFile(W, H)
    End With
    With New WIA.ImageProcess
        .Filters.Add .FilterInfos!Stamp.FilterID
        With .Filters(1).Properties
            Set !ImageFile.Value = New WIA.ImageFile
            !ImageFile.Value.LoadFile "bg.png" 'Background PNG.
        End With
        Set Picture = .Apply(BackImgF).FileData.Picture
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to load the PNG from a resource you can do that as well.

If you must support Win2K or WinXP, or even WinXP SP1 or later but you do not have or do not want to deploy the redist WIA 2.0 library then you'll need a 3rd party GDI+ wrapper.  Otherwise you could use the GDI+ Flat API calls.  That is perfectly viable too but more work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using LaVolpe's AlphaImageControl for years, it supports PNG/raster images. When downloading the files and sample app, you need to manually register the control using regsvr32 if you are using Windows 7 and up. You then need to pass a reference to the control in your components list and voila, you have a control that does magic for vb6. The files can be found at vbForums - [HERE](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630193-vb6-Alpha-Image-Control-v2-Final-Update-(15-Jan-2012))